# Which music players support DAAP?

Tags: music-player

Which music players support DAAP? I can only find:

- [DAAP Media Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mult.daap)
- [SharePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afqa123.shareplay)

Does anyone know any others? I really don't understand why the popular music players don't support DAAP. I want to be able to stream my mp3 from my NAS to my phone :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [some available](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=DAAP&c=apps) from Google Play Store. Excluding the ones you've mentioned, this two I've used, and they worked very well:

- [Music Pump DAAP Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.berard.musicpump) by Android Music Pump:

  > Music Pump is a feature rich Android DAAP Client that lets you to stream and sync music from your PC or NAS to your android device. All you need is a DAAP Server.
- [Remote for SoundBridge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kompf.android.rokucontrol) by Martin Kompf:

  > - Connect to different music servers including UPnP, DAAP, and Internet radio.
  > - Browse playlists, artists, composers, albums, songs, genres, and folders at music server.

Answer (score 1):

DAAP is developed by Apple, and they don't license it to Android devices. The handful of players you found have reverse engineered the DAAP protocol (or an older version thereof), but no 'official' publisher can publish it with permission of Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has [a list of DAAP clients for all platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol#DAAP_clients).